# EL expressions are not evaluated in JSP

Tags: jsp, el

My index.jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        ${item}<br>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet:

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");
        list.add("Item 3");
        
        request.setAttribute("list", list);

        System.out.println("Servlet is working!!!!");
        
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

In the console I see the message “Servlet is working!!!!”, that is, the serverlet responds to the browser request and sends the page. But list parsing does not happen. Instead of a parsed list I see this in my brouser: "${item}"!!!

My project structure:
[image: My project structure]

Comment: You need to change JSTL libraries to confirm your app's JSP version.

Comment: @RomanC: Nope. See abovelinked duplicate for the actual answer and in-depth technical explanation about the relation between JSTL and EL and how the web.xml could influence that.